# updating checkbox value to database

Tags: php, mysqli

im trying to update checkbox value into database. i already write some code and it worked updating the database..however for some reason i got undefined index in my combobox variable..here is my code..

code to display existing data into checkbox

```
<tr>
    <td><label for="cbPin">Pin this  post</label></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="cbPin" class="checkbox checkbox-warning" id="cbPin" <?php 
    if ($pin == 0) {
      ?> value="0" <?php
    } else {
      ?> checked value="1" <?php
    } ?>
    /></td>
  </tr>
```

this one is variable to render the form

```
 $pin = $row[9];
```

and this one if button submit clicked

```
$pin = ($_POST['cbPin']);

if ($pin == '') {

  $pinpost = 0;

} else {

  $pinpost = 1;
}
```

and this is my query

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE tblanouncement SET title = ?, message = ?, pinpost = ? WHERE anouncementId=?"))
  {

    $stmt->bind_param("ssii",$title, $message, $pinpost, $id); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A checked checkbox sends its name and value.

A non-checked checkbox is not a successful control and won't be submitted at all.

If you aren't dealing with multiple checkboxes of the same name, use `isset` to see if the data exists or not. Don't assume you will have a value for it in the POST data array.

Comment: ty..i have added isset in my post variable and its work..i;ll mark ur answer after this web allow me to mark